# does Prepare For Segue work when data send by second view controller

Tags: ios, swift3, prepareforreuse

i'm new to ios development 
few days back when i was learning how to send data from one VC to anotherVC then i used

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: self) {
if segue.identifire == "segue1" {
let data = segue.destinetion as! secondViewController
data.labelName = labelFirst.text
}
```

and now when in receiving data from secondVC then i also using almost same code 
as i saw on web

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "segue2" {
            let secondVC = segue.destination as! secondViewController
            secondVC.delegate = self
        }
    }
```

so plz anyone can explain real quick why does it look same 
or what's difference

Comment: this method is called when a segue is about to be performed from the viewController to another, this method is the way to access to destinationViewController and pass some needed data to him using the segues approach

Comment: i think you are using two segue one A to B and second B to A that why it look like same.

Answer (score 0):

To send data back from secondVC to firstVC rather use delegates. Based on the line "secondVC.delegate = self" that you wrote, you already read an article on this and might just need some additional info.

In secondVC put the following code outside of the class scope. for example above

```
class secondVC: UIViewController {}
```

The code to place there is

```
    protocol secondVCDelegate {
       func didFinishTask(returnData: String)
    }
```

Put the following line inside of the class scope of secondVC

```
var delegate: secondVCDelegate?
```

Then in firstVC inherit the secondVC delegate by adding secondVCDelegate to the class. (e.g: `class firstVC: UIViewController, secondVCDelegate {}`)

Then add the function to your firstVC

```
func didFinishTask(returnData: String) {
     //Do something here with returnData
     print(returnData)
}
```

Hope this helps!